# I am not at all able to paint weight paint on the plane

Tags: particles, weight-painting, subdivision-surface, vertex-weights, weight-paint-mode

I am new to Blender and I am using Blender 3.0.0
I am trying to weight paint this plane but I am unable to do it to at least a single vertex. I subdivided the plane many times but I am unable to paint. What am I doing wrong?

[image: plane]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Weight paint is a somewhat confusing term, because you're really only painting the vertices.  To be able to cover the plane with finer granularity, you need to subdivide it, giving it more vertices to work with.  Weight painting, after all, is just a visual way to set the weights in vertex groups.

Here's a plane that's been subdivided:

[image: subdivided plane]

Here's the same plane in weight paint mode after I've made a diagonal pass with the weight brush:

[image: same plane with weight paint.]

Notice how the red areas are centered on the vertices along the diagonal?
The other colors represent Blender extrapolating weights between vertices, from Red being a weight of 1 through green to Blue being a weight of 0.

Comment: Note: with Triangulate modifier you can observe at what direction will be weight extrapolated (you can better predict a result).